# Keras - adding a layer in front of a model

Tags: keras

What I'm trying to do is to add a Upsampling2D layer in front of a imported VGG16 model. However I have no idea how to that, never seen such thing mentioned anywhere in the internet.

What I tried to do:

```
VGG = VGG16()
model = Sequential()
model.add(UpSampling2D((32,32), input_shape=(7,7,3)))
model.add(VGG)
```

However trying to use this model for anything raises the following error:

> AttributeError: Layer model_1 has multiple inbound nodes, hence the notion of "layer output" is ill-defined. Use `get_output_at(node_index)` instead.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

You can provide the `input_tensor` argument in `VGG16()`.

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.layers import Input, UpSampling2D
input_tensor = Input(shape=(7, 7, 3))
upsampled = UpSampling2D((32, 32))(input_tensor)
VGG = VGG16(input_tensor=upsampled)
```

By running `VGG.summary()`, you should see something like:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param # 
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 7, 7, 3)           0
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_1 (UpSampling2 (None, 224, 224, 3)       0
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      36928
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 112, 112, 64)      0
_________________________________________________________________

...
```